# Creating a Master file shared across multiple document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document

I'm creating a SharePoint Online site with multiple document libraries, and there are documents that it would be nice if I could access it from more than one library. Additionally, if the doc is updated in one, it should be updated across all of them. Maybe even have one as a master file and the rest just child links.

My current solution is to create link entries that lead to the master file, but my VP wants the links to look like the original (i.e. show up as a word or excel doc type without .url in the name). Bonus point if the gallery view shows a proper preview. Is there a way to accomplish this with links or could there perhaps be a better way?

Thanks,
Luis